# Beta Function proof help

Tags: beta-function

I'm trying to prove that beta(x,y)=beta(x+1,y)+beta(x,y+1) but not sure where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$B(x+1,y)+B(x,y+1)=\int_0^1\left(t^x(1-t)^{y-1}+t^{x-1}(1-t)^y\right) dt=$$

$$\int_0^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\left[\require{cancel}\cancel t+1-\cancel t\right]dt=B(x,y)$$

Answer (score 1):

You have probably proven that
$$ B(x,y) = \frac{ \Gamma(x)\Gamma(y) } {\Gamma(x+y)}$$
where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function and also that 
$$\Gamma(x+1) = x\Gamma(x).$$
Then we have
$$B(x+1,y) + B(x,y+1) = \frac {\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(y) + \Gamma(x)\Gamma(y+1) } {\Gamma(x+y+1)} = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)(x+y)}{\Gamma(x+y)(x+y)} = B(x,y).$$